# Creating a generator in a Python function call - why does this work?

Tags: python, syntax, iterator, generator

I am confused why this code works. In a call to all() I can use syntax which appears like code to generate a list comprehension, but without any parentheses other than the pair for the argument list. Executing the same code outside the argument list results in a syntax error.
Calling print on the same code results in the creation of a generator, but without using yield or the (generator comprehension parentheses) ?

Is this special syntax applicable to only function calls, or am I missing something?

```py
all(i for i in range(1, 11)) 
# True

print(i for i in range(1, 11))
# the syntax is creating a generator?
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000CDD7CC00>

i for i in range(1,11)
#   ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `all` will take an iterable, and a generator is an iterable. If you want to print it, use arg unpacking like `print(*(i for i in range(1, 11)))` or, more succinctly `print(*range(1,11))`

Comment: Generator expressions need the `(...)`, but when the expression is the *only argument to a call expression*, you can omit the extra parentheses.

Comment: Also see [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how the syntax is explicitly defined, see [the original PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#id16):

> if a function call has a single positional argument, it can be a generator expression without extra parentheses, but in all other cases you have to parenthesize it.